# Using Lodash with create-react-app results in "Uncaught TypeError: _this.reduce is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, create-react-app

I'm new to React and `create-react-app` and I'm attempting to use Lodash in my `App.js` file and I'm running into an error. `Uncaught TypeError: _this.reduce is not a function`. I've added

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import shuffle from 'lodash/shuffle';
import random from 'lodash/random';
import find from 'lodash/find';
```

to the top of my `App.js` and

```
import Lodash from 'lodash';
```

in my `index.js` file.

For testing I've used this `reduce` example from MDN, which works:

```
  var total = [0, 1, 2, 3].reduce(function(sum, value) {
    return sum + value;
  }, 0);
```

But the line that uses lodash throws the error above:

```
  var books = _.shuffle(this.reduce((p, c, i) => {
    return p.concat(c.books);
  }, [])).slice(0, 4);
```

In this case `this` is an array like this:

```
var data = [
  {
    name: 'Mark Twain',
    imageUrl: 'images/authors/marktwain.jpg',
    books: ['The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn']
  }
];
```

Comment: Why are you using `this` instead of just using the object pointer `data`?

Comment: could you try doing: `const self = this;` then use `self` inside of `_.shuffle` instead of `this`. like: `self.reduce`.

Comment: @Pytth because it's in a function definition for `data.selectGame = () => {....}`. So `this` should refer to `data`, right?

Comment: @MarkyDD: No; `() =>` gives you the `this` _of its definition_.

Comment: I was not aware of that @SLaks. I changed all references of `this` to `data` and it works now. @Pytth or @SLaks, you should create an answer for this and I'll accept it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Using console.log to print out variables that you're working with is a handy tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments section, your `this` reference is not pointing to what you expect.

Change it to `data` and it should work.

Comment: To expand on this: using `data.selectGame = function() {....}` makes the use of `this` valid, while using an arrow function `data.selectGame = () => {....}` does not. This is because an arrow function _does not bind its own `this`_ ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code its very unlikely that the keyword `this` actually refers to the array. Near impossible I would say. You could maybe write a whole book on how the `this` keyword behaves in Javascript. The `_this` value is a how babel handles the different behaviors of `this`.
Consider this example:

```
console.log(this)

function someFunction(){
  console.log(this);
  const someSubFunction =  function() {
    console.log(this)
  }
  someSubFunction();

  const someOtherFunction =  () => {
    console.log(this)
  }

  someOtherFunction();
}

someFunction();
```

This code is transpiled by babel to:

```
"use strict";

console.log(undefined);

function someFunction() {
  var _this = this;

  console.log(this);
  var someSubFunction = function someSubFunction() {
    console.log(this);
  };
  someSubFunction();

  var someOtherFunction = function someOtherFunction() {
    console.log(_this);
  };

  someOtherFunction();
}

someFunction();
```

Notice how the `this` value is reassigned to a variable called `_this`.

In this example, all of the log statements print out `undefined`. If you use the keyword `this` at the root scope then it will (almost) certainly be `undefined`. In fact if you look at line 3 of the transpiled example, babel literally just replaces `this` with `undefined`. Inside a function on the global scope, `this` is also `undefined`.

Inside a class `this` refers to the instance of the class if you are directly inside a method defined by the class, or in the constructor.

Anyway long story short, you need figure out what this is actually referring to. Most likely you just need to assign your array to a variable and do:

```
var books = _.shuffle(data.reduce((p, c, i) => {
  return p.concat(c.books);
}, [])).slice(0, 4);
```

If you are going to do lodash though, you could also be consistent and just use lodash like this:

```
var books = _.chain(data)
   .reduce((p,c,i) => _.concat(c.books), [])
   .shuffle()
   .slice(0,4)
   .value();
```

Slightly easier to read in my experience.